# Webform can't display the form

Tags: webforms

Webform can't show the form.

The form is showing correctly until today I just found out the form can't display.

It shows me the message "**You may not submit another entry at this time.**"

How do I solve it?

Drupal 6

I made the changes for **Total submissions limit: Unlimited**, but still same problem.

After made the changes, error message below shown:

> user warning: Unknown column 'total_submit_limit' in 'field list'
>   query: UPDATE webform SET nid = 110, confirmation = '',
>   confirmation_format = 3, redirect_url = '', status = 1,
>   block = 0, teaser = 0, allow_draft = 0, auto_save = 0, submit_notice =
>   1, submit_text = '', submit_limit = -1, submit_interval = -1,
>   total_submit_limit = 10, total_submit_interval = 3600 WHERE nid = 110
>   in /home/domains/site.com/public_html/includes/common.inc on line
>   3538.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to update your database with update.php (http://www.YOUR-DOMAIN.com/update.php) or with drush : `drush updb`
The error says that your are missing one column in DB...